# Absolute path in bash scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I've got a shell script `myscript.sh` which calls a command, let's say `mycmd`.
When i run that script from the terminal, e.g. `./myscript.sh`, everything works fine.

But when i add that script to the crontab, the output of `mycmd` is empty. When i call `/usr/local/bin/mycmd` inside of `myscript.sh` everything works fine again.

So why i have to use the absolute path of the executable? Is it because it is not in the `$PATH` of the "cron-bash"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have it exactly right - the environment of `cron` may have a `PATH` that does not include `/usr/local/bin/`.  You can fix this by, in your script, appending that directory to the `PATH`:

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/"
```

The best practice, though, is indeed to use explicit paths for all external binaries that a script calls just in case (for instance) a maliciously designed program conveniently called `cp` gets dropped into the `PATH` somewhere before `/bin`.

Comment: Thank you! But why they have varying `PATH`s? I thougt that the script runs "directly" from the users bash in the background.

Comment: Cron's very limited environment is for security reasons.  You can see (and fiddle with, if you like) them in `/etc/default/cron`.